# Should I be worried about this crack?

Tags: foundation, crack

We recently moved and noticed this forming. Should I be concerned?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this an interior or exterior wall? What kind of building material is behind the surface coating?

Comment: Pick more of that covering off to see if the crack goes deeper.  Right now it looks like just the decorative covering has the crack and is not structural.

Comment: It looks like the resurface layer is debonding possibly water behind is it puckering? There could be termite, ant or rot issues with some puckering, but this kind of looks like moisture behind, it’s best to investigate and put a new coat on if just de bonding.

Comment: Is this near a window opening?

Comment: Hello - Yes, there is a sliding door below it

Comment: @ed beal, we are in Florida so that could be possible. It has been really cold lately and have noticed crown molding caulk crack as well. I am more worried about this crack as it seems to be growing. Do you think I should get a structural engineer?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @freeman, I am not sure. It is a 1997 Florida home that we just purchased